# Ocultar un DIV dentro de un loop the posts

Tags: php, div, hide

tengo un Loop para mostrar unos Post, pero en base al valor the uno de los campos del post, quiero mostrar u ocultar el elemento completamente. el código actual es el siguiente. Aunque he intentado dentro poner una if cuando recojo el valor del campo para en funcion de su valor ( si es 1 se muestra y si no se oculta el div).
El campo proviene de un Campo Personalizado ACF. y lo recojo con the_field('publicado'), y en funcion de ese valor quiero mostrar el div  u ocultarlo.
Alguna idea de como hacerlo.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
```

'>
        );'>
        
    
    
        '>

### D.O.:

```
        <div class='oxy-post-meta-author oxy-post-meta-item'>
            <h2>Uva<?php echo "\t" ?>: <?php the_field('uvas');?></h2>
        </div>

        <div class='oxy-post-meta-comments oxy-post-meta-item'>
            <h2>Bodega<?php echo "\t" ?>: <?php the_field('bodega');?></h2>
        </div>

        <div class='oxy-post-meta-comments oxy-post-meta-item'>
            <h2>Precio<?php echo "\t" ?>: <?php the_field('precio_restaurante');?>€</h2>
        </div>

        <div class='oxy-post-meta-comments oxy-post-meta-item'>
            <h2>Precio Tienda <?php echo "\t" ?> : <?php the_field('precio_tienda');?>€</h2>
        </div>
        <div class='oxy-post-meta-comments oxy-post-meta-item'>
            <h2>Publicado <?php echo "\t" ?> : <?php the_field('publicado');?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class='oxy-post'>
 <a class='oxy-post-image' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>
  <div class='oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio' style='background-image: url(<?php echo the_field('imagen'); ?>);'>
   </div>
   </a>
    <div class='oxy-post-wrap'>
        <a class='oxy-post-title' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <div class='oxy-post-meta'>
            <div class='oxy-post-meta-date oxy-post-meta-item'>
                <h2>D.O.<?php echo "\t" ?>: <?php the_field('denominacion_de_origen');?></h2>
            </div>

Comment: Lo mejor es que desde la consulta filtres para obtener solo los que tengan el valor adecuado.